# How to center form fields and toolbar buttons?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am working in extjs4. I am geting stuck at a point where I want to format items in a panel at a center position properly. But I don't know how.

[image: Here Is my registarion form view]

Actually I want to display all items at middle position not left side..also I want display submit button at center position but it get display at left side.. I am facing this problem...

here Is my some code :

```
Ext.define('Am.user.Registration',  {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    //extend:'Ext.window.Window',
    id:'registationId',
    alias:'widget.Registration',
    title:'Registration form',
    resizable:false,
    buttonAlign:'center',
    closable:true,
    titleAlign:'center',
    //autoScroll:true,
    draggable:false,
    //shadow:true,
    height:350,
    width:800,
    floating:true,
    bodyPadding: 30,
    //collapsible:true,
    requires:[
             'Balaee.view.sn.user.Captcha'
              ], 
     defaults:{
        //align:'center'
        defaultAlign:'t1-c'
     },         
     //bodyStyle: 'align:center',        
   // Ext.require(['Ext.form.field.Date']);
    items:[
    {
        xtype:'combo',
        fieldLabel:'Language',
        name:'language',
        emptyText: 'Language',
        store: ['Marathi','Hindi','English'],
        queryMode: 'local',
        editable:false
    }, 
    {
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        layout: 'hbox',
        combineErrors: true,
        defaults: {
            hideLabel: true
        },
        items: [
            {xtype: 'textfield',    fieldLabel: 'First', name: 'firstName', emptyText: 'First name',width: 80,  allowBlank: false,margins: '0 5 0 0'},
            {xtype: 'textfield',    fieldLabel: 'Middle', name: 'middleName',emptyText: 'Middle name', width: 80, allowBlank: true, margins: '0 5 0 0'},
            {xtype: 'textfield',    fieldLabel: 'Last', name: 'lastName', emptyText: 'Last name',width: 80, allowBlank: false,
                validator: function(value) {
                    var password1 = this.previousSibling('[name=firstName]');
                    return (!(value === password1.getValue())) ? true : 'Dont give first name and last name same.'
                }                           
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        xtype:'textfield',
        fieldLabel:'Primary email',
        name:'primaryEmail',
        //anchor:'100%',
        allowBlank:false,
        emptyText: 'Email',
        vtype:'email'
        //labelAlign:'right',
    },
    ---------------
    --------------
    ],//End of items square
//  buttons:[{
//      xtype:'button',
//          formBind: true,
//          fieldLabel:'submitttttttt',
//          action:'submitAction',
//          text:'Submit',
//          defaultAlign:'t1-c'
//  }   
//  ],
    bbar:
    [
        {
            xtype:'button',
            formBind: true,
            fieldLabel:'submit',
            action:'submitAction',
            text:'Submit',
            defaultAlign:'t1-c'
            //flex:6,
        },
    ],//End of buttons square
});// End of login class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply an [HBox](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox-cfg-pack) layout (with pack: 'center') to your form and ditto for your toolbar.

You can see an example of how this is done for the form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315120/1179377). And for the toolbar:

```
var toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
    dock: 'bottom',
    layout:{
        pack: 'center'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'foobar',
        handler: function(){
           alert('ok');
        }
    }]
});
```